# What's the regex to replace <foo> with FOO?

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a buffer with a lot of instances of words surrounded by '<' and '>', and I want to replace them all with the just capitalized word. E.g. `<foo>` -> `FOO`.

I read the regex chapter of the gnu emacs manual, but I'm still lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace next occurrence after point:

```
(progn
  (re-search-forward "<\\(.+?\\)>")
  (upcase-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
```

`re-search-forward` searches for the next match of `<foo>`.
You can find a fairly detailed explanation on 
[Emacs Wiki on Regexp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).

After Emacs matches the next occurrence of regexp,
calling `match-beginning` and `match-end` will return the 
position of the beginning and the end of the match.

The number `1` in the argument means the first group of the match,
that is the part of regexp in the first (and in this case, the only) pair of parenthesis.

Finally `upcase-region` will upcase the text in the range marked by `match-beginning` and `match-end`.

Code above only replaces the next occurrence.
Since `re-search-forward` returns `nil` when failed and `t` when succeed,
we can ask Emacs to keep going until no further match is found:

```el
(while (re-search-forward "<\\(.+?\\)>" nil t)
  (upcase-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! However, it's replacing <foo> with <FOO> and not FOO without the delimiters. But I just did want I wanted with `M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> <\(.+?\)> <RET> \,(upcase \1) <RET>`

Comment: Try this variant: `(while (re-search-forward "<\\(.+?\\)>" nil t) (replace-match (upcase (match-string 1))))`

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't read the question as carefully as I should. Since you have the answer and mine isn't valid, how about you move your answer to the question's comment and I remove my answer?